# how to get value from one activity to another using putExtra?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

```
public class RecyclerAdapterNew extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataHolderNew> {

    @Override
    public DataHolderNew onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_values, parent, false);
        return new DataHolderNew(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataHolderNew holder, int position) {
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.getExtras("transfer",);//i have to transfer the value of the 
        //textview by converting into int and transfer into another class
        holder.table_value.setText("table values: "+(position+1));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is your question actually?

Comment: i want to tranfer the nos. value to another class which is displayed by the recyclerview ...how should i do? @pskink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following in the calling/invoking activity "-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,CalledActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(NameKeyforvalue,value); ......

startActivity(intent)
```

and use the following in Called/Invoked (receiving) activity :-

```
variabletoholdvalue = getIntent().getStringExtra(NameKeyforValue);
```

Note! getIntExtra, getLongExtra etc... (some require default, getStringExtra doesn't)

Answer (score 1):

public class RecyclerAdapterNew extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
@Override
public DataHolderNew onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_values, parent, false);

    return new DataHolderNew(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataHolderNew holder, int position) {
    Intent intent=new Intent();

    int value = intent.getIntExtra("transfer",);
    holder.table_value.setText("table values: "+(position+1)*value);

}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 10;
}
```

}

Comment: here is the second class i want to transfer the value to